# Traducir "lock" vs "close" en español

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

"Closed" en inglés significa "cerrada" mientras que "locked" significa "cerrada con llave (o similar mecanismo de seguridad)".

Llevo un buen rato pensando y no encuentro un verbo en español que venga a significar lo mismo. Lo único que se me ocurre es `asegurar`. No sé si esto es debido a esa gran facilidad que hay en inglés de transformar verbos en nombres y viceversa:

> **Lock** (as verb)
>
> to fasten or secure (a door, window, building, etc.) by the operation of a **lock** or locks.

y como nombre

> any device or part for stopping temporarily the motion of a mechanism.

entre [otras posibles acepciones](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lock). Por lo que "lock" viene a significar "candadear", si yo pudiese hacer lo mismo en español con "candado", por ejemplo.

¿Qué verbo hay en español que pueda usarse para mantener esas connotaciones de "lock" de "cerrada con llave" (o candado u otro mecanismo de seguridad)? Como a mí solo se me ocurre "asegurar", `The door is locked` debería ser

> La puerta está **asegurada**

que podría valer, pero ni de lejos me parece óptimo. Además tiene doble significado (asegurada de incendios) por lo que hay cierta ambigüedad. `Atrancada`, que es otra opción, puede sonar a que la puerta no funciona bien (no abre, pero no por un mecanismo de seguridad, sino por un fallo).

¿Hay algún verbo (y prefiero que sea un único término, en lugar de usar "cerrada" y añadir con *pestillo, llave, candado y cadenita*) en español que funcione como equivalente de `lock`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay dos posibilidades principales, y luego algunos préstamos posibles.

A pesar de que *atrancar* tiene un doble significado de cerrar con tranca y obstruir, la forma no prefijada **trancar** solo contempla la primera acepción (bueno, tiene una segunda acepción que nunca se confundiría):

> **[trancar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aHHbYU6)**
>   **1.** *tr.* Cerrar una puerta con una tranca o un cerrojo. || **2.** *tr.* Dar trancos (‖ pasos largos).

También hay otra opción, aunque limitada geográficamente:

> **[candar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=75R8vzP)**
>   **1.** *tr. Ast., Pal. y Sal.* cerrar (‖ asegurar con cerradura u otro instrumento). ||
>   **2.** *prnl. Ar. y Sal.* Dicho de un río, de un arroyo o de un depósito natural o artificial de agua: helarse (‖ solidificarse).

No suelo escucharlo mucho en Asturias, de hecho, lo asocio fuertemente con el habla salmantina.  Y para que no penséis que cito *candar* por ser asturfalante, antes de que hable del asturiano, echemos un vistazo a los otros idiomas ibéricos para ver cómo hacen diferencia.

Diría que mirásemos primero al catalán para otras posibilidades, pero (corregidme si me equivoco) la única palabra en él es *tancar*.  En portugués, no obstante, usan *trancar* para cerrar con llave y *fechar*  para cerrar genéricamente (*fecha a porta e **tranca-a***).  En gallego, usan *cerrar* en sentido genérico y <sup>fechar</sup>/<sub>pechar</sub> para con llave (*Cerra a porta e **<sup>féchaa</sup>/<sub>péchaa</sub>***).  El asturiano emplea *zarrar*, sentido genérico, y *pesllar* cuando hay llaves (*zarra la puerta y **piésllala***).

A pesar de tantas opciones en el alrededor, en castellano, creo que lo mejor sería emplear *trancar* que ya disfruta de gran uso en el portugués y no se limita (según el DLE) a zonas geográficas particulares como *candar*; pero si no te gustan, pues tienes *pechar* o *pesllar* como buenas alternativas ibéricas.

Comment: Efectivamente, en catalán no se me ocurre otra palabra que no sea _tancar_.

Comment: De hecho sí había considerado _tancada_, que es de lo poquito que sé en catalán, pero revisando en la web no me dio a entender que realmente tuviera la connotación de "cerrada mediante mecanismo" frente a la simple posición de "cerrada". _Candar_ es una opción genial. No lo conocía, y se ve que sí podemos hacer como en inglés con _lock_ verbo y _lock_ sustantivo.

Comment: I would have said that the English equivalent of _trancar_ was to bolt the door, not lock it. That does not mean it is not the best available translation of course.

Comment: "lock" a veces se traduce como "trabar" (no sólo en el caso de puertas, sino en general), pero puede tener el significado de "bloquear", o sea, impedir la apertura mediante un mecanismo no habitual o convencional.

Answer (score 3):

Por dar otras opciones y aportar más variedad. Igual no te lo crees pero el DLE recoge el verbo "llavear":

> **[llavear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NUcEBGg)**
>
> 1. tr. Arg. y Par. Cerrar con llave.

Lo único que pasa es que solo se usa en Argentina y Paraguay. Otra que ya había sido apuntada por guifa como perteneciente al gallego pero que resulta que ha pasado al castellano:

> **[pechar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SGIH5Ir)**
>
> De *pecho*.
>
> 1. tr. Gal., León y Sal. Cerrar con llave o cerrojo.

De uso en Galicia, León y Salamanca. Y por último otra también algo sorprendente:

> **[apestillar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=39Y84rv)**
>
> 1. tr. Cerrar o encerrar con pestillo. U. t. c. prnl.

Comment: Genial respuesta. "Llavear" viene a ser muy parecido a "candar". En el fondo yo busco un "cerrar" independiente del mecanismo. "Pechar" es otro térmno genial. Qué pena que no tenga un uso más extendido.

Comment: Curiosamente, yo he visto un par de veces *llavear** no para significar *cerrar con llave* sino *habilitar una puerta con una cerradura*.  No sabía *apestillar*, pero tampoco sabía la palabra *pestillo* antes jaja.

Answer (score 2):

En España lo mas coloquial y similar a **lock** sería el verbo `echar`, que en el contexto de cerrar es practicamente un equivalente, ya que su uso es generalmente con cosas con cerradura, el verbo `echar` en una de sus acepciones se describe de la siguiente manera:

> **Echar**
>
> 10. tr. Dar a una llave, un cerrojo, un pestillo, el movimiento necesario para cerrar.

En el sur, es habitual escuchar expresiones como

> **Lock the door.**
>
> Echa la/s puerta/s. (Cierra la/s puerta/s con llave)
>
> Echa la llave *(omitido, ...de cualquier cerradura; puerta; coche; candado... según contexto)*
>
> Cierra con llave. (Cerrar la/s puerta/s con llave)

Otros contextos de uso habitual, podrian ser

> Echa el coche. (Cerrar las puertas del coche con llave)
>
> Echa la casa. (Cerrar la/s puerta/s de la casa con llave)
>
> Echa el garaje. (Cerrar el garaje con llave)

Cuando hacemos referencia a cosas sin cerradura, simplemente significa cerrar, por ejemplo:

> Echa la persiana. (Cierra la persiana y cierrala con llave si tiene)

También podriamos usarlo para decir que algo esta cerrado con llave

> La puerta está echada.
>
> El coche esta echado.
>
> Tiene la habitacion echada.

---

Traducciones como trancar o atrancar, me paracen forzosas o fuera de lugar directamente pues no implican cerrar con una cerradura, más bien sería cerrar con una tranca, estaca, cerrojo... hoy día trancar o atrancar son de uso menos frecuente (estamos rodeados de cerraduras).

Answer (score 0):

En México se dice

**poner seguro**

Por ejemplo, si nos estacionamos en el centro de la ciudad donde los robos son más frecuentes, podría decirle a mi hijo,

> Hay que poner seguro aquí en el centro.

Esto funciona para las puertas también.

No sé, quizás se va a oir raro en algunos países, pero en México es exactamente equivalente a "lock."

Pero si vas a poner seguro a una puerta con candado, entonces sería

**poner candado**

[image: candado]